# Random Primes between 4000000000 and 4294967291 (C++)

Tags: algorithms, prime-numbers

What is an efficient way to find a random prime between $4000000000$ and $4294967291 $ in C++?

This is what I wrote, but it is ridiculous:

```
unsigned long long rand_prime()
{
vector<unsigned long long> vect_prime;

int count = 0;

for( unsigned long long i = 4000000000 ; i <= 4294967291 ; ++i )
{
    for( unsigned long long j = 1 ; j <=i ; ++j )
    {
        if( i % j == 0 )
        {
            ++count;
        }
        cout << "CAT";
    }

    if( count == 2 )
    {
        vect_prime.push_back( i );
    }
    cout << "DOG";
    count = 0;
}

return vect_prime[ rand() % vect_prime.size() ];
}
```

It takes so long to get to DOG.

Comment: Generate a random number $n$ in that range and test it. Repeat if necessary (you have a 4% chance of hitting a prime and can improve this to 12% by simply ensuring $n\equiv \pm1 \pmod 6$)

Comment: What? How did you get that congruence?

Comment: $n$ should not be divisible by $2$ or $3$. -- You are not trying to store the 12.7 million primes in that range in an array, are you?? Anyway, you definitely need a better primality test than trial division (and even trial division can be a lot faster if you test only to $\sqrt n$ and only odd divisors)

Comment: How do you know that?

Comment: Yeah, I know. It was a terrible idea. I didn't really think about that till I saw how many CAT's I had on the screen.

Comment: I thought there were 13.3 million primes.

Comment: http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=primes+between+4000000000+and+4294967291

Comment: Yeah, 13.3 it says on my screen. That's exactly where I checked too.

Comment: Why not use an existing bignum library like openssl and http://ardoino.com/2005/11/maths-openssl-primes-random/

Comment: Oh, OK. How do I implement it?

Comment: Alright, I eyeballed the number per $\frac n{\ln n}$ only. So your chance of hitting a prime is slightly larger (and your need to store if you really took that approach would also be higher)

Comment: @Amzoti "A quirk of the prime generation algorithm is that it cannot generate small primes. Therefore the number of bits should not be less that 64." Here we are looking for 32bit primes, so I guess the approach to simply generate random integers and test (faster than trial division though) is to be preferred.

Comment: I would do something like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13665443/generate-random-prime-number-in-c-c-between-2-limits

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's some simple code. It can be improved, but this version takes about 25,000 divisions compared to 1,223,372,019,527,422,987 in your version (making it several trillion times faster).

```
int isprime(unsigned long long n) {
  /*if((n&1)==0) return n==2;*/
  if(n%3==0) return n==3;
  /*if(n<25) return n>1;*/
  unsigned long long p = 5;
  while (p*p <= n) {
    if (n%p==0) return 0;
    p += 2;
    if (n%p==0) return 0;
    p += 4;
  }
  return 1;
}

unsigned long long rand_prime(int lower, int upper) {
  unsigned long long spread = upper - lower + 1;
  while(1) {
    unsigned long long p = 1 | (rand() % spread + lower);
    if (isprime(p)) return p;
  }
}

/* Usage:
unsigned long long r = rand_prime(4000000000, 4294967291);
*/
```

The basic idea: generate a random number in that range, then test it to see if it's prime. Instead of checking for divisibility by all numbers up to the number being tested, it checks only the odd numbers not divisible by 3 up to the square root of the number.

This could be improved with Miller-Rabin pretesting, or even a Lucas test to prove primality below 2^64.

Comment: Nice code. One problem is that your `isprime()` function fails when checking values over 18,446,744,030,759,878,679 (0xFFFFFFF600000017), Any larger value will cause an infinite loop, because the sequence which starts at 5, skipping by 6, ends up hitting 0x00000000FFFFFFFB ... 0x0000000100000001 and squaring the latter value wraps you back to 0x0000000200000001. The next lower prime to 0x00000000FFFFFFFB squared (0xFFFFFFF600000019) is 0xFFFFFFF600000017, so that is the effective limit to your algorithm.

Comment: ...The limit can be increased to 0xFFFFFFF9FFFFFFC5--expanding the range by 17,179,869,102 candidates--by adding another check against `p * p` in the loop right after the `p += 2`. That part of the cycle will land on 0x00000000FFFFFFFD, whose square is still in range. It appears that you want just one multiplication per cycle, though, and if you ***move*** the check instead of adding an additional one, you'll miss finding prime `5` (only) at the start of the sequence. At this point resolving all this can be left to personal preference.

Comment: Based on and inspired by your code, here's what I came up with for for a 64-bit unsigned `IsPrime` function that fixes the problem I described above. It allows checking values up to 0xFFFFFFF9FFFFFFC5 and has zero multiplications--just the 1 mod operation--per loop. This code checks within and between every 2 / 4 cycle, so it also avoids one extra mod about half the time... https://pastebin.com/H2m7KMMK

Comment: @GlennSlayden Right, I definitely want to avoid the extra operation per loop. But if you're working with numbers that large you definitely want to use BPSW rather than trial division.

Comment: You forgot to compliment my [pastebin code](https://pastebin.com/H2m7KMMK) **:-)**  I not only avoided the 'extra' multiplication per cycle, but also got rid of the one you had left. Was there some reason you were avoiding using `sqrt`?

Comment: @GlennSlayden I avoided sqrt because floating-point errors can throw it off. It's not much work to check and correct but it would make my code more complicated. (See for example [here](http://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/cgi-bin/gitweb.cgi?p=pari.git;a=blob;f=src/kernel/none/mp_indep.c;hb=4a9fdea56591504362dde09d461bdfc646c57a6d#l886).) But yes, sqrt is definitely the way to go.

Comment: I thought it was throwing me off too, but then I realized that IEEE double-precision `sqrt` (at least the one I'm using, `Math.Sqrt` in *.NET*) basically has the same limitations as `ulong` (`unsigned __int64` to you), and so the real problem was that this type of brute-force approach--regardless of doing it via `p * p` or `sqrt`--can fundamentally only go up to 0xFFFFFFF9FFFFFFC5.

Comment: @GlennSlayden No, IEEE double precision has only 53 bits of precision so it fails ~2000 times earlier.

Comment: Oh drat. I battered my code with many millions of cases, but maybe never found the exact problem range. To be fair, my tests were mostly focused on values *just immediately below* the patently-excluded range (0xFFFFFFF9FFFFFFC5, 0xFFFFFFFFFFFFFFFF] (as well as near the 32/64-bit boundary area), and might have missed very-high values a bit further *below*.

Comment: @GlennSlayden No worries, the exceptions are pretty sparse. But regardless, for numbers this large (rather than the 32-bit numbers in the question) you really want to use BPSW which is 1000+ times faster.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to represent all the 32-bit primes as map of odd numbers representing each odd number with a bit. It takes about 256 megabytes for this map, but memory is cheap these days. (If you only represent the odd 32-bit numbers greater than 0x40000000, this map will be a lot smaller, but you should first compute all of the 32-bit primes.) Since 256 megabytes is manageable, this means you can use a sieve to compute all of the 32-bit prime numbers, setting a bit in the map if a number is prime and otherwise leaving the bit 0. On my old Mac Pro computer, it takes hours or less to run the sieve (implemented in C++). Once this is done, you can find the bit nearest to any number and the search up and down in the map to find the nearest prime number to that number. So, trading memory for speed in this way, you can get the nearest prime number to any randomly-chosen number very quickly!

Comment: A map of 32-bit prime numbers could possibly also help in finding 64-bit prime numbers. One can use the primes in the 32-bit map for test divides to determine whether a 64-bit number is prime.